# Absolute positioning relative to second parent

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to position an absolute element based on second relative parent?

```
<ul> <!-- This has position:relative; -->
    <li> <!-- This has position:relative; -->
        <ul> <!-- position:absolute this relative to the parent ul -->
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul{
    position:relative;
}

ul > li {
    position:relative; /* I need this because of pseudo :after */
}

ul > li ul{
    position:absolute;
    left:0; /* This is what i want to do. Left based on parent ul not parent li... */
}
```

Comment: Basically....No. You might need to re-think the structure depending on what you're doing with the `li:after`.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible. An absolute element can only position itself based on the first relative parent.